# Flask HTTP Method Not Allowed Message

Tags: python, flask, http-status-code-405

```
from flask import Flask, render_template,request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/',methods=['post'])
def main():
    if (request.method=="POST"):
        text=request.form('write')
        if(text==None):
            text=""
    else:
        text=""
    return render_template('form.html',text=text)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I want to receive only POST method. So I set `method` option to `methods=["post"]`. But it always sends `HTTP 405 Not Allowed Method` error.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Using Tag</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="write">
    <input type="submit">
    </form>
    {{ text }}
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to know reason why this application only sends HTTP 405 response.

Comment: Your methods should include both `GET` and `POST`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the HTML form from `/` path you need to enable both `GET` and `POST` request in that route. Otherwise when you try to access the root path `/` from your browser, you will get the `HTTP Method not allowed error`.

`app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def main():
    text = ""
    if request.method == "POST":
        text = request.form['username']
    return render_template('form.html', text=text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

`templates/form.html`:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Using Tag</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="write">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
{{ text }}
</body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

[image: output]

**Explanation (Updated):**

- To access the form value use `request.form['INPUT_FIELD_NAME']`.
- We are making `GET` and `POST` requests to the `/` route. So, we set `GET` and `POST` requests in the `methods` options of the `/` route. When we are viewing the page using the browser, we make `GET` request to that page. When we submit the form, we make `POST` request to that page. In this case, we are storing the form value in the `text` variable and pass the value to the template. For `GET` request we are showing the empty `text` value.

The above snippet is the same as the following snippet:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def main():
    if request.method == "POST":
        text = request.form['username']
        return render_template('form.html', text=text)
    elif request.method == "GET":
        return render_template('form.html', text="")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**References:**

- [Flask documentation for request object](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/quickstart/#the-request-object)

Comment: Thank you very much! and do you know why i should include "get" method in the option even though i only use POST method?

Comment: @Kernel_Handler, you are welcome! I have updated the explanation.